# How does employment termination affect German work visa?

Tags: working-visas, germany, resident-permit

I've been hired by an IT company in Germany. Based on the employment contract, I applied for the work visa in the embassy. After few months I got work visa for 6 months and on my passport there are two pages, one stating company name and on the other page there is my photo and some information like visa validity etc.

It was my second day in the company when I got an emergency in my family and I've to go back to my country. My employer wanted to fill this position urgently because they were in severe need of hiring someone to kick some important goals and I wasn’t available to work for nearly a month or two, so unfortunately we mutually decided to end this contract. And on the next day I moved back to my country to sort out the issues.

I've work visa valid until January 2018, so being present in my home country, my question is, can I still work and live in Germany or in other words can I return back to Germany to search a new job on the same visa?

Highly appreciate answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got answer to this problem from German embassy.

I talked to the German embassy who issued this visa, they said that your visa was issued to work for that particular company (as you can see the sticker on your passport) so you can't return to Germany on the same visa. If you do it will be considered as illegal entry and you have to face all the consequences. So I've to repeat the whole process that is, get a new job offer first and then apply for a new work visa.